# not able to build in clearcase snapshot csproject

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, clearcase, csproj

I am using clear case as my source control and i have snapshot view of all my projects(C#) . Some of the common projects are shared among them.

Now i have 5 projects in my solution and they have clear dependencies among them (No circular dependencies) . Project 5 refers to the project 4 i have build project 4 successfully and project 5 could not found referred dll on its location . But when i see it physically it is there.

Now the problem here is when i try to create a new snapshot view and build again it will build successfully . This is quite irritating to create a new snapshot view for frequent changes in the projects. Can any one suggests an alternative.

PS: My thoughts on this it should not be a Visual studio problem it should be clearcase problem

Additional INFO: Visual studio 2010 express edition, Clearcase 7.1.2.6  ,

Error: -> Error 84  The type or namespace name 'Project4' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

i have recently noticed that adding dll of project4 to project5 will not give any error but if you try to add reference by csproject it will give an error. Does this makes any sense ? 
Any help would be better for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the dll file, but it is not somehow available for Visual Studio to use, perhaps its state isn't correct:
In command-line, go to the parent folder of that file, and do a:

```
cleartool ls
cleartool descr -l yourFile.dll
```

Maybe it isn't readeable, because it is taken by another process.

The other reason a file isn't readable is mentioned in "[About the pathname limitation on Windows and its affect on ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21120400)" and [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21256146):

> There is a limit of 255 characters for any label, branch, hyperlink, or attribute name.

Make sure no pathname is too long in your project.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate reply but the description shows it has read and write and protection as nobody what does this means.

Comment: @ansar What error message do you see when building project 5?

Comment: Error 84 The type or namespace name 'Project4' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to follow Output window and Warning window. Then i realized that visual studio was not able to find csproj file in my file system. Then i have changed name of the view it works.

The problem is path of cs project it is referring to it was exactly 256 characters and according to some of the internet threads . cs proj file will not be located if your physical path + referred path = 256 characters.

thank google for this resolved issue else i would've struck with this problem like for ever ..

I know that i have mentioned not related to Visual studio stuff. Till i know the problem it has been resolved.

Thanks all.

Comment: I have documented the pathname limitation in my answer.