# File Not Loaded Checked out but Removed error

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I am try to deliver code from my dev stream to QA stream and the delivery is erroring out(unable to merge) one particular file. When I look at the file from Clearcase Explorer, it is showing the file state as 'Not Loaded, Checked out but removed" as shown in the screen shot below:

[image: status]

When I try to do a UndoCheckout from Find Checkouts I am getting the below error:

[image: errror]

```
Error undoing the check out for 'Z:\buildSupport\...'
Not an object in a vob: 'Z:\buildSupport\...'
Pathname provided did not resolve to a version object.
Not an object in a vob: 'Z:\buildSupport\...'
```

From Command Line I am getting below error when tried to get status of the file

```
cleartool ls AuditAssignment.jsp
cleartool: Error: Pathname is not within a VOB: "AuditAssignment.jsp"
```

Please help to solve this issue. I am in a UCM environment.

Comment: I was able to UndoCheckout from command line but the merge issue is still not resolved. Everytime I resume the delivery operation the file AuditAssignment.jsp goes into state "'Not Loaded, Checked out but removed" in the target view. Please provide suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`Z:\` suggests a snapshot view which has been [mapped to a letter drive through `subst`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2324719/6309).

Depending on your exact OS, it could be a case of path length limit that I mention in "[not able to build in clearcase snapshot csproject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21931966/6309)".

But you also have other causes, like this [IBM technote suggests](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21134397):

> When the link is created with a relative path using the wrong case, even though the link is created, the files within that linked directory can only be viewed through the Windows command line (`cmd`). However, they are treated as if they are not in version control anymore.

Even if symlink is not involved here, check if there is a case issue (with the same name versioned but with a different case, like the status picture seems to indicate)

Windows would not be able to show, especially in a snapshot (UCM or not) view, two files with the same name and different cases.

It is important when the merge is done that a file '`AuditAssignment.jsp`' is present on both sides with the *same* case.
Once the case is identical on both side, *then* a merge can be attempted.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons. 
Among them, the protection (access permission) of the parent directory might not allow you to modify it. You should check the Clearcase permission of the directory "fieldAudit". You can do so by right-clicking on the directory and look at the Clearcase property. If you are not the owner and if the group you belong to does not have the permission to modify the parent directory, you might get into this type of issue. In order to modify the access permission of the parent directory, you can will have to use the "[cleartool protect](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21211784)" command, either as the VOB owner or either as the owner of the element. 
The command would then be (for Linux/Unix):

```
cleartool protec -chmod 770 fieldAudit
```

What matter is the 7 for the group. You could give 775 or 777 (which would not be safe) depending on the policies for your VOB. Your Clearcase administrator should be able to help you on that one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have proper explanation for this issue. A senior person from another team helped and i couldn't follow what he did exactly. Basically he deleted the file from my view and recreated it. He did this a couple of times.Sorry I am not able to answer this properly.